# $A^TA=AA^T$ implies $A$ has orthogonal eigenvectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, orthogonality

Need help to prove the following.

> For any real matrix $A$: $A^TA=AA^T$ implies $A$ has orthogonal eigenvectors.

Also, does it work the other way around?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We use MathJax formatting. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Unless $T$ refers to the "conjugate transpose", it matters whether $A$ is real

Comment: You are probably meant to assume that $A$ is real. In that case, it also works the other way around (as long as we allow complex eigenvectors/eigenvalues).

Comment: Real matrices only then, complex eigenvalues and eigenvectors allowed

Comment: Looks like we need to use the singular value decomposition.

Comment: This result is called the spectral theorem for normal matrices. You should be able to find a proof by googling

Comment: Are you aware of "Schur triangularization"?

Comment: For the "other way around", you need to be more specific. E.g., $\pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}$ has orthogonal eigenvectors but is not a normal matrix at all.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I'm self learning from Gilbert Strang's textbook and lectures and this is beyond their scope. I'll try to look for intuitive/basic proofs for it (if you are familiar with some, any useful links would be great). Thank you

Comment: @idanp for example, you'll find a proof of Schur triangularization in Friedberg, Insel and Spence's Linear Algebra

Answer (score 0):

Its true other way round too. Let $A$ has orthogonal eigenvectors, then $A=Q\Lambda Q^T$ for some orthogonal matrix $Q$ consisting of the orthogonal eigenvectors. Then $AA^T=Q\Lambda Q^TQ\Lambda Q^T=(Q\Lambda Q^T)^TQ\Lambda Q^T=A^TA.$